# Uploading data using a form PHP no file actually uploading

Tags: php

Ok so basically i have two functions set up to show a form else upload the data if the form is submitted.

```
function showResourceForm()
 {
 echo("
 <form   enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form1' method='post'      action='tutorAddResource.php' 
>
<table>
<tr><td> Name Of resource</td><td> <input type ='text' name='name' /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Available From</td><td> <input type = 'date' name = 'from' /> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Available Until</td><td> <input type = 'date' name = ' until' /> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Choose Resource</td><td> <input type = 'file' name 'file' id= 'file'> </td></tr>
</table>
                        <input type='submit' onclick='submit'  value='Upload Resource' />
</form>
");
```

}

This is the function for showing the form setting the enctype to allow for data upload

```
function doResource()
{

$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$until = $_POST['until'];
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$ow = $_SESSION['userID'];

$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","root","aceTraining");   
$sql = "INSERT INTO resource (name, dateFrom, dateUntil, ownerID,filename   ) VALUES ('$name', '$from', '$until', '$ow','$file')";
mysqli_query ($conn,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
doSQL($sql);

 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
     echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     }
   else
     {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "\uploads" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Uploaded To: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 }


}
```

And this is the function that saves the files details into the table and is supposed to save the file in uploads, however does not the error code gives me undefined index file in developer mode, however i am hesitant to mention that as the duplicate questions containing this error code do not seem to apply to my issue or i do not posses the php knowledge to correctly extract the information from them in such a raw form.

Notice: Undefined index: file in \xammp\htdocs\aceTraining\tutorAddResource.php on line 46 is my error code, the same for line 54 60 61 and 62 also
line 46 is shown below

```
     $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Comment: why you have added `doSQL($sql);` when you are using mysqli_query?

Comment: `"\uploads"` is almost certainly not a correct path to move the file to.

Comment: Well you refraining to show us the error message makes it a lot harder to answer your question. Maybe it's not a duplicate, but if it were, you made it more difficult for yourself to know.

Comment: Also note that your code is open for SQL injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your code it seems you have typo in your code

```
 <input type = 'file' name 'file' id= 'file'>
```

change your code to

```
     <input type = 'file' name='file' id= 'file'>
```

Comment: Small things can make a big difference, nice spotted :P

Comment: Thank you so much, this has solved every error code however i still do not properly upload the file.

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL Don't forget to `chmod` the folder(s) to `777` (If you using a online webhost)

Comment: @C0dekid.php I'm guessing from their confusion between forward and backslash that they are actually hosting this on Windows. I could be totally wrong about that though.

Comment: @c0dekid.php I'm using a xammp apache server on windows, this website is not for actual business use just learning php.

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL Ah, no need for `chmod` then, try to switch the slash from `"\uploads"` to `"/uploads"` :-)

Comment: @c0dekid.php sadly this has not fixed my issue, thank you for your time however.

Comment: `"\uploads" . $filename` will move the file `foo.txt` to `C:\uploadsfoo.txt` ... IF the webserver is allowed to write there. You most probably want to change this to `uploads/`.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider sadly this has not fixed it either, i must have a fundamental problem elsewhere i guess i will look over my code again.

Comment: i guess use full path so instead of /uploads  use something like C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/

Comment: Thanks guys i have fixed it with your help :D